# Получить значение из элемента

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование, javascript

Получаю некоторые данные, хранящиеся в элементе:

```
var result =  $(this).data('calculator').data[material][diameter];
```

Затем модифицирую результат:

```
$.each(result, function(key, value) {
    result[key] += modifier;
});
```

Если снова извлечь данные из объекта, то они будут модифицированы. Очевидно, что переменная `result` содержит ссылку на значение. Каким образом мне получить само значение так, чтобы мои манипуляции не влияли на исходные данные?

Пробовал так, но результат тот же:

```
result = function(){
    return me.data('calculator').data[material][diameter];
}();
```

Comment: @co11ter, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

[[@co11ter](/users/8357/co11ter)](/users/8357/co11ter), я не совсем понял, что требуется, но вы можете скопировать объект, используя

```
var cloneObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, originalObject);
```

Comment: Да, пойдет. Спасибо!